# Why does it use 'their'?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> Every year the Netherlands sends 20,000 tulip bulbs to Canada to thank 'them' for 'their' aid in the Second World War.

I understand that **them** and **their** is used to say about Canada, Why do they not use **her** or **its** or **his**?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the words **their** and **them** are mainly in context.

Here, one is not referring to the country(the land) itself, but the people. Therefore,

> Every year the Netherlands sends 20,000 tulip bulbs to Canada to thank **them** for **their** aid in the Second World War.

refers to the **Canadians** who receive gratitude and originally helped the Dutch, making the subject plural.

However, if we refer to the country itself, it is used as a singular noun:

> Canada **is** North of the United States.

Answer (score 1):

> > Every year the Netherlands sends 20,000 tulip bulbs to Canada to thank 'them' for 'their' aid in the Second World War.
>
> I understand that **them** and **their** is used to say about Canada, Why do they not use **her** or **its** or **his**?

We do not know why "they" used *them* and *their* instead of *her* or *his* or *its.* After all, we cannot enter into the mind of the person who wrote that sentence and capture their reason or reasoning.

We also do not know why *you* used "they" in:

> Why do they not use **her** or **its** or **his**?

But, in general, *they* is often used as a singular, [gender-neutral pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_and_gender-neutral_pronouns#Alternatives_to_generic_he) that can refer to a masculine, feminine, or neuter antecedant.

You can see this in Sentences 22 and 48 on [this page](http://www.samuelbass.com/stori3s--opinions/archives/04-2013):

> 22. For someone, somewhere in the world, today is the most amazing day of their life.

and

> 48. Somewhere, someone is losing their virginity right now.

*Their* is a singular pronoun that can refer to a feminine, masculine, or neuter subject. The most natural way to read this sentence in conext is to read *they* as referring to either a male or female human.

Also, *they* can refer to as unspecified or unknown person. This is one reason to explain the usage in your sentence:

> Why do they not use **her** or **its** or **his**?

We do not know who "they" is or are, but we know it is somebody.

That same page above has the sentence you ask about as

> 24. Every year the Netherlands sends 20,000 tulip bulbs to Canada to thank them for their aid in the Second World War.

Now, *they* and *their* could be gender-free pronouns that refer to the country of Canada. After all, *Canada* is the closest noun.

Traditionally, the feminine pronoun *she* was used to refer to countries, as well as to ships.

So, it is very possible that the writer was using the gender-free pronoun instead of *she* to refer to Canada. However, we can't get into their mind and find out.

Besides *Canada,* the pronoun *they* could be referring to Canada's *government.* But again, we can't be sure.

To say that *they* and *their* refer to the people of Canada is also only a guess. If I were going to refer to the people of Canada, I would specifically say so:

> Every year the Netherlands sends 20,000 tulip bulbs to the people of Canada to thank them for their aid in the Second World War.

OR:

> Every year the Netherlands sends 20,000 tulip bulbs to Canada to thank its/her people for their aid in the Second World War.